# mvc: annotation driven behaviour

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am just learning Spring and Spring MVC and I used dispatcher configuration in XML file and used @Controller and @RequestMapping to map my request to /home.

It was all working fine, however, what I noticed was when I added this line,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

I got this error message,

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/creditcardapp/home] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

So I added `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` config and it started to work fine.

So my question here is, why is annotation-driven tag not needed when I did not use the resource mapping locator and why it stopped mapping controller after I added that?